# Image won't load in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to load an image... it's in the same folder and I'm not getting any errors as far as I know everything should be fine... I'm not quite sure what's wrong... if you have any ideas let me know in the comments! thanks for helping!

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas
var ctx
window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas")
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50)

    var img = new Image();

    img.src = "scp.png";

    ctx.drawImage(img, 145, 145, 50, 50);
    
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown)
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp)



var Xspeed = 0
var Xpos = 10

setInterval(draw, 50)

function keyUp(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 32) Xspeed = 0

}
function keyDown(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 32) Xspeed = 2
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 999, 999)
  Xpos = Xpos + Xspeed
  ctx.fillRect(Xpos, 0, 20, 20)
}



</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are constantly drawing over the picture in the `draw()` function. You can add the

```
var img = new Image();

img.src = "img_the_scream.jpg";

ctx.drawImage(img, 145, 145, 50, 50);
```

into the draw function which will show to image and the square.